# Apache2 server not accesible from outside of localhost

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, apache2, ruby-on-rails

So I've followed some guides and I managed to put the server up but for some reason it can only be accessed through localhost in my laptop(windows and the ubuntu virtual machine), when I try to access through the ip on my desktop it doesn't work even though they're on the same network, I turned off the firewall on windows and ubuntu just in case.

this is what my port.conf file looks like

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

this is what myapp.conf file on sites-available looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 10.0.2.15
    DocumentRoot /home/david/myapp/public
    RailsEnv development
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory "/home/david/myapp/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And the apache2.conf file is the default one, the only difference is that I had to add the passenger module to get it to work with rails

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2
     PassengerDefaultRuby /home/david/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/ruby
   </IfModule>
```

Any idea why I can't access to the server through its ip address only from localhost?

Comment: Do you use a router? Have you forwarded port 80 through the router to the machine with the server on it?

Comment: @Organic Marble Well I'm very new when it comes to this, I'm running the server on virtualbox and I forwarded the port there, when I was trying to do it in the router it said "The IP address is not in the same subnet with LAN IP address.", I tried using the ip address given on ubuntu with hostname -I, should I use the ipv4 from the host instead of the vm?

Comment: I use "bridged adapter" setting in the Virtualbox network settings, that gives the virtual machine a real IP address on the LAN.  Then you can forward port 80 in the router to that IP address.

Comment: I finally solved it thanks to the hint you gave me, I was using NAT that just forwards the port to the vm and that's why the ip I was getting from hostname -I wasn't the one that I had to access to rather the one of the host machine, I was stuck at this for 3 hours! I feel so bad haha Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. I'll post my suggestion as an answer, feel free to accept it if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using "bridged adapter" setting in virtualbox, this will give the VM a real address on your LAN, and you can then forward port 80 to it in your router, allowing access from the outside world.